# Error deploying webjob schedule - Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict)

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a project with three scheduled webjobs. They all deploy correctly from Visual Studio, but it can't create a schedule for the third one. I get the following error:

> webjobs.console.targets(110,5): Error : An error occurred while
>   creating the WebJob schedule: Response status code does not indicate
>   success: 409 (Conflict).

There's nothing special about my schedule in webjob-publish-settings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "...",
  "startTime": "2015-12-07T00:00:00-05:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Day",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

I tried adding the schedule manually from the Azure portal and got a bit more information.

> Job collection 'WebJobs-EastUS' reaches maximum number of jobs
>   allowed.

It turns out that you can only have 5 jobs per collection. This project has 3 jobs and two environments, so there are 6 in total. I created a new job schedule in a new collection, then deleted the job, and tried redeploying to see if it used the new empty collection. It did not, and I got the same error.

Next, I deleted a job in the original collection and redeployed. That time it worked fine. This isn't an ideal solution, since I'm still limited to 5 jobs when I need 6.

Is there a way to specify the job collection to use for the scheduler? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You might consider using the new inbuilt scheduling mechanism detailed here: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs. There are no job limits imposed there.

Comment: However, if you want to continue using Azure Scheduler, you should be able to use the old portal, navigate to Scheduler/JobCollections and increase the scale on your Scheduler JobCollection to increase your limit. This blob post shows where to find this stuff in the portal: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html

Comment: @mathewc That's a great point, I didn't realize we were using the free tier.

Comment: @mathewc scaling up fixed it. If you add that comment as an answer, I'll accept it. I'll look at the new scheduling mechanism too, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage the scale of the Scheduler JobCollection used by your WebJobs in the old portal. Navigate to Scheduler/JobCollections and **increase the scale** on your Scheduler JobCollection to increase your job limit. This [blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html) shows where to find this stuff in the portal, and also details how WebJobs + Azure Scheduler work behind the scenes.

However, we highly recommend using the new **inbuilt** scheduling mechanism detailed in [this blog post](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs). This mechanism keeps the schedule with your job and involves no outside dependencies.